# How to change password, email and meteor profile

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

Hello friends some can point me some material like make the change of password, email and in the profile add new fields like sex, age city add photos. Without using the collection or aldeed-autoform.
  All doing with my own code so having a little more control some alded-autoform select functions like select or datepicker do not look great in the design.

[Something like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAYGY.png)

```js
Template.update.events({
  'submit form' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;

    var oldPass = $('#password');
    var newPass = $('#password-new');
    var verifyPass = $('#password-confirm');

    if(newPass.val() === verifyPass.val()){
            Accounts.changePassword(oldPass.val(), verifyPass.val(), function(err){
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    let profile = {
                      address: {
                        city: target.city.value,
                        street: target.street.value
                      },
                      gender: target.gender.value,
                      favoriteColor: target.favoriteColor.value,
                    }
                      console.log("datos actualizados");
                }
            });

            oldPass.val('');
            verifyPass.val('');
            newPass.val('');

        } else {
            console.log("password no match");
        }
    //}
    console.log(profile);

    Meteor.call('updateUser', profile);
  }
});
```

```
{
  _id: "bbca5d6a-2156-41c4-89da-0329e8c99a4f",  
  emails: [
    { address: "cool@example.com", verified: true },
  ],
  createdAt: Wed Aug 21 2013 15:16:52 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  profile: {
    name: "Joe Schmoe",
    phone: "5555-555-555",
    gender: "male",
    city: "DC",
    country: "USA",
      birthday: "01-01-2017"
  }
```

Comment: you can create your own "components" to use with autoform, you don't have to rely on their default components.

Comment: Can you show me how to do some documentation? @zim

Comment: doc is here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#defining-custom-input-types , i can post an answer w/ some example code if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcelrama,

I will share how I am doing this. For my project I am storing things like a skype Id and time zone. So when I go to create a new user in Meteor Method

```
    Accounts.createUser({
        email: 'example@example.com',
        password: 'testing',
        profile: {
            name: "Jack",
            gender: "Male",
            skypeid: "jack123",
            timezone: {
                name: "UTC",
                offset: "UTC"
            }
        }
    });
```

You can also do something like this.

```
let newUser = { ... };
let user = Accounts.createUser(newUser);
```

Storing it in a variable returns the Mongo Id.

Then when you go to update profiles, you can do it like this.

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: user }, { $set: { "profile.name": "Jake" } });
```

If you use Meteor.users.update on a field that does not exist yet, it will create that field with the value you specify, but make sure you use the "quote marks" around the keys.

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: user }, 
  { 
     $set: { "profile.address.city": "Orlando" } 
  }
);
```

Here is the official documentation. http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html

Here is a very Basic example

Packages ---

```
meteor add accounts-base
meteor add accounts-password
npm install --save bcrypt
```

Template ---

```
    <template name="signup">
     <form>
      <input type="email" name="email"><br>
      <input type="password" name="password"><br>
      <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
   </template>
```

Event ---

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';    

   Template.signup.events({
      'submit form' ( event, template ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const target = event.target;

        let newUser = {
          email: target.email.value,
          password: target.password.value,
          profile: {
            name: target.name.value
          }
        }

        Meteor.call('createNewUser', newUser);
      }
    });
```

Method ---

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

Meteor.methods({
  'createNewUser' ( userObj ) {
    let user = Accounts.createUser(userObj);

    user = Accounts.users.findOne(user);

    console.log(user);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks @jkdowdle , for responding to assign the input data to what you mention

   ` <Input type = "text" name = "city" id = "city" class = "form-control"`<br/>

<br/>
``Meteor.users.update ({_id: user},
   {
      $ Set: {"profile.address.city": "$ ('# city'). Val ();" }
   }
);``
<br/>



For the password I understand that it is done with `Accounts.changePassword` but I did not understand how to adapt it or make it functional, could you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry for the bad edit, I'm very bad editing or trying to adjust the code here  @jkdowdle

Comment: @Marcelrama, I just added a basic example of how to create an account, just to clarify, are you asking how to change a users password? I could give you an example of that if you like

Comment: If right ,I can already add users what ,I can not edit their fields for my start I just ask for an email and password, but after registering, I want you to fill in the other fields like sex, city, phone, country, photo, as you mention can be created with

      $ Set: {"profile.address.city": "Orlando"}

Then besides all that I also want the user to change or update their password, email and name along with those other new fields. I have tried with the documentation but it is very complex it is not so detailed for someone who is starting to work co meteor.

Comment: I agree it can be difficult to understand the documentation. let me give an example of how to update the profile from a "profile page"

Comment: Ok thank you very much appreciate that help I carry these days giving me hard to get understood I have only managed to login register a user and send welcome email and forget password

Comment: @Marcelrama, I just added a new answer, let me know if that makes more sense!

Comment: Ok thanks again, but the password field still understand how to perform the update Accounts.changePassword();

Comment: Ok to reset a password in meteor, the way I have done it, you will have to do a couple of steps. First use Accounts.forgotPassword(options, [callback]) to send a link that has a token in the URL then you use that token in this function Accounts.resetPassword(token, newPassword, [callback]). http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-forgotPassword. I don't think I can give you an example at the moment as it is a long proccess and will depend on the router you use to get the token from the url

Comment: Hello sorry for not answering before, I mean to change the password in conjunction to update data and showed me in the fields of color, city, street, want an additional email address and password, when user update these fields also must be updated in conjunction with the password. according to the documentation listed on Accounts.changePassword ();

Comment: hey @jkdowdle  I am trying to change the password as I told you adapt this new part that I left the updated in my post but I only get an error 400, according to the documentation are the permissions to be able to enable the password change but also the assets and nothing Work enablePasswordChange: true

Answer (score 0):

## Update User Profile

#### Template

```
<template name="update">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="gender"><br>
    <input type="text" name="favoriteColor" placeholder="color"><br>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city"><br>
    <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="street"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</template>
```

#### Client Event

```
Template.update.events({
  'submit form' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target;

    let profile = {
      address: {
        city: target.city.value,
        street: target.street.value
      },
      gender: target.gender.value,
      favoriteColor: target.favoriteColor.value,
    }

    console.log(profile);

    Meteor.call('updateUser', profile);
  }
});
```

#### Meteor Method

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.methods({
  'updateUser' ( profileObj ) {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();

    console.log(userId);

    Meteor.users.update(
      { '_id': userId },
      { '$set': {
          'profile.gender': profileObj.gender,
          'profile.favoriteColor': profileObj.favoriteColor,
          'profile.address': profileObj.address
        }
      }
    );

  }
});
```